# Why don't we give users below 250 rep notion about close votes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, new-users

To clarify beforehand: I'm not asking for leaving auto comments as with close voting a question as a duplicate.

Why aren't low rep users notified when they receive a close vote/flags with their question?

[With a rep of 250](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes), you can spot and track close votes, as well as vote for closing/reopening your own questions.

I'm often combining down- and close-votes, and OP's comments about asking why the question was downvoted appear (=> leads to unnecessary noise). This mostly applies for users below 250 rep.

As mentioned in my introductory, I'm not asking for an automatically created comment explaining the close vote, because that certainly would attract too much biased and lemmings voting behavior.
But I think the OP should be notified, if that's not implemented already.

---

Here's a good actual sample, why I think question OPs should be notified (I've left a comment in this particular case):

[Resources for learning QScintilla and writing a QSciLexerCustom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731117/resources-for-learning-qscintilla-and-writing-a-qscilexercustom)

---

As for the [android tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300464/why-dont-we-give-users-below-250-rep-notion-about-close-votes#comment227242_300468) related comment: I oftenly see c++ related questions tagged along [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) without any legit relationship to android specifics regarding the actual c++ code. Though these questions seem to receive notoriously 
unjustified upvotes. That seems to be a problem specific to the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) community.

Comment: Users with 250+ rep get to see close votes on their own Q I believe and for duplicates they get a banner visible to them saying they can agree with the dupe (insta-close) or edit their post - there's a MSO post with that in I think... I just can't find it at the second :p

Comment: Tagged as discussion and support, sounds like feature-request... What are you looking for here?

Comment: @JonClements Wouldn't be a notification useful to educate 1 rep users as well?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'd worry that at 1 rep they're not yet familiar enough with the site and how it works and it 1) won't mean anything to them, 2) confuse them or 3) possibly scare them

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not sure about a feature request, because I don't know if the feature exists meanwhile. My own experiences are way back in time, but it seems there aren't any notifications for the OP, besides for duplicate close votes.

Comment: @JonClements I'm no more afraid of _scaring_ by any means. That walls and waves of crap coming in are huge.

Comment: @JonClements your argument basically says "nobody lurks or reads the tour before asking, we can't expect people to be able or willing to learn, also they might get scared". To which I say: so what? If anything, showing users who don't know anything about closevoting that somebody voted to close the question is a learning opportunity; it's their problem if they don't take it. And if they get scared, that's not a bad thing IMO - right now a majority of new users don't seem to even understand that SO has quality restrictions, so being scared of them is an improvement.

Comment: Related: for when the deal is done http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-gets-closed?s=1|0.4140

Comment: What would be the gain of having this system set in place? Right now the main (only?) advantage that I see is that the user could start working on fixing the question before it is closed (if it ever is, that it may not be), and see more cons than pros: new users could find it confusing/threatening, notification flooding, unnecessary noise in the question (user commenting "_who/why did I get the close vote?_")...

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Will go that way before or after the close process is completed, what's the actual difference in recent noise like you mentioned?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If it goes the same way, how does SO/SE improve with this suggestion? About the noise, the potential (that not actual) difference would be getting noise up to 5 times (once for each close vote "_why the close vote? and now why? and this one?..._", unless the notification isn't sent with each of them) instead of 1 time now ("_why was my question closed?_")

Answer (score 37):

I see a handful of types of new users that this would apply to.

#### 1) The Ask and Go User

This user asks their question and leaves. They don't respond to comments, they don't respond to votes, they don't respond to edits, and they don't respond to answers. They simply post the question, and then check back in a day or two to try any answers. If they interact with the site again in any way, it would be unsurprising if it was with a different, and unregistered, account.

These notifications would matter not for this user. They would likely use <strike>an unregistered</strike> a throwaway account, never use it again, and therefore never even see the notifications about the close votes. Even if they saw them, they wouldn't pay any attention to the reasons or try to learn from them.

#### 2) The "Help Vampire" User

To this user, Stack Overflow is only here to answer their questions. Their question can be utter crap, yet they require an answer to it. If their question is so much as looked at wrong, they will get agitated and demand an explanation in the comments, potentially (though not always) causing unnecessary discussion in the comments that can quite easily devolve into an argument.

Notifications of close votes would potentially enrage this user. As they see Stack Overflow as a help site and not a site with defined rules and guidelines, they would potentially see this as a sign of the rumored "elitism" on Stack Overflow.

**However,** some users that fall into this category could *potentially* be helped by these notifications. These notifications, and a brief discussion in the comments about the close reasons, *could potentially* help these particular users see that Stack Overflow is *not* a help site and has a quality standard to which their question must abide.

It's hard to say, from my perspective, which outcome is more likely with this class of user, but it is largely going to be a case-by-case scenario.

#### 3) The Troll and The Spammer

I'm lumping these two together as one class because the notifications would mean the same to them: Absolutely nothing. In theory, at least in my mind, a "troll" question in this case would be one posted by a user who *knowingly* posted an off-topic questions just to enrage other users. Either case is likely to get shut down very quickly, but in both cases the notification would do absolutely nothing for the low rep user.

#### 4) The Misinformed User

This user simply does not understand that they have done something wrong. Perhaps they just did not provide enough information, or they have worded their question in a way that makes it *sound* off-topic when it really isn't. Maybe they are not a native English speaker and did not realize that the way they phrased their question did not convey what they really meant. The user has tried to understand what Stack Overflow is for, and has at least looked at a few questions before asking their own, but something just hasn't quite hit home for them yet.

Users in this class *can potentially* be helped by these notifications. They can see the close reasons and try to understand how they apply to their question. If they don't, they can ask in the comments for clarification. These users would, hopefully, be willing to learn and become productive members of the community.

These users can still react poorly, of course. These users could misunderstand downvotes and close votes and take them personally, leading to the potential arguments mentioned in class 2. This class of user is *by no means* a perfect class- We are all humans, after all, and humans are in no way perfect. Misunderstandings and arguments can still occur.

#### Conclusion

These notifications could *potentially* help newer users... In some cases, at least. I feel like class 2 users outnumber class 4, however, and that the angrier class 2 users outnumber the calmer ones.

I feel, personally, that these notifications would cause a bit more trouble than they would fix *or* would be completely ignored and wouldn't help at all. Others may disagree, of course, but is this something that is worth developer time? Do the potential positives outweigh potential negatives and potential pointlessness? I don't think we'd help enough users to be near worthwhile.

If the suggestion was only to remove the reputation restriction to see close/reopen votes on one's own question, I would have far less problems with this, as it would likely be a simple change for the team. If that were the case, I would suggest that the ability to *cast* those votes on one's own question remain locked to 250 rep and above, as new users may misunderstand and attempt to "close" their question when it was solved, or try to incorrectly reopen their question when it was closed.

<sub>Note: This answer assumes the case of 100% correct close votes. There are of course cases of incorrect close votes, and those would be a (potentially small) problem all their own.</sub>

Comment: Following your argumentation, I actually don't see the problem. For class 1 users, it doesn't make any difference neither for them, nor for us - same for class 3. If a class 2 user becomes angry - so what? They would probably show the same behavior, when the question gets closed. Finally at least some class 4 users would benefit. So in the end it would be a gain for at least some of the new users and changing the rep limit doesn't sound like it would require a lot of effort - we are not talking about introducing and fine tuning a new feature here..

Comment: You might want to emphasize the confusion a closing/reopening/deletion-in-progress would cause which, though someone once started it, will never get anywhere. Also, you might want to stress that we don't want to overload new users with the mechanics of SO, it's hard enough getting them to write a coherent question (and perhaps take the tour / read the most obviously pertinent parts of the help-center, if they are ambitious).

Comment: There seems to be a lot of *Ask and Go* users.

Comment: In high traffic tags, you'll find a lot (if not a majority) of users from category 1 and 2, and not the calmer ones. I haven't seen much of category 3, and category 4 would not really be helped by additional clues because those users pay attention and respond to comments made on their question anyway.

Comment: @2Dee Class 4 could be helped, actually- Sometimes close votes are left without comments explaining what was wrong with the question. In those cases, a class 4 user could see the extra information and use it. I do agree that in the cases where comments are being made and responded to it would pretty much just be redundant, if the question even got close votes at that point. Class 3 users, as I said, get shut down pretty quickly usually, so that would likely be why you don't see many of them.

Comment: @MikeMB As I said in my last full paragraph, that part is really my personal opinion on how helpful I feel these would be. I don't feel we would teach enough users with this feature to really make it worth developer time. I fully expect disagreement with that opinion. And yes, actually, if you read the comments down below Bradley's answer, we actually _are_ discussing a new feature: Sending a notification to a user when a question receives a close vote. (Which is what I understood the question to be asking for in the first place.) That _would_ require more effort.

Comment: @Kendra: Sorry my mistake then. If we are talking about something that actually needs significant developer time to implement, I completely agree with you.

Comment: @MikeMB It's fine- You weren't the only one to think the OP meant just removing the 250 rep restriction. If that was indeed what was being asked, I wouldn't be nearly as against it myself. It's really just a line of if it's worth developer time.

Comment: @Kendra at least on the tag I'm visiting often (android), I see a lot of reasons to close that are wrong. I mean, the questions are bad, but people usually don't bother trying to find a good reason to close, they just want to close. The result is a *What is Android* question might get flagged as a *question asking us to recommend a tool/book/resource*. Showing this type of voting to the users would not be ideal, but you're right, it's probably better than nothing.

Comment: @2Dee Well, my answer actually specifically does not address that scenario. I feel that that scenario, where the close vote is either completely off-base or completely unnecessary because the question is good, would be a problem in its own right that would have to be taken into consideration before this feature could be implemented.

Comment: You should probably rename "Help Desk" user to "Help Vampire". It's the more recognized term around here.

Comment: @Mysticial Updated.

Comment: users can't ask from unregistered account [since 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107163/165773): "registration is required to ask questions (but not to answer)"

Comment: @gnat Strange- I've seen users with "unregistered" accounts and no answers that "joined" more recently than that, and links to said "unregistered" accounts from Meta. I will update to account for this either way, thanks. (Edit: Just realized that's mainly been on other sites, and that change, given Jeff's answer, may have just been an SO change, which would make sense.)

Comment: @NeilG so, you're going around blasting people who leave downvotes without comments, [because a user downvoted your post and left comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946284/does-a-yaml-bash-block-need-a-chomp-modifier-or-is-it-better-without)

Comment: No, @KevinB, I'm not "going around", I don't have the time. However, there are high rep users who are definitely "going around" all the time, dishing out hundreds of down votes and close votes almost daily without good reason. I'm not "blasting" anyone about that, whatever "blasting" is, I'm drawing attention to a problem. This content around this question seems heavily focused on low end behaviour from low rep users but is studiously avoiding the problems amongst moderators. You seem a bit  touchy about trying to correct that imbalance?

Comment: @NeilG i mean, you' keep talkin as if there's some crazy number of posts being downvoted, but like, there's literally 80% more upvotes than downvotes, so that's clearly not the case. You also seem to be complaining about a user that literally edited your post into shape, left comments trying to improve the question, who then deleted the comments after you became hostile over them trying to help you. I'm sorry for my lack of sympathy for such an absurd scenario.

Comment: @KevinB, it's hundreds a day for some users... they seem to spend about 2 minutes thinking about a question, get it wrong, down vote, close vote, and never come back to find out they were wrong about it, unless it's just briefly to delete comments that expose their errors...

Comment: @NeilG it's, not, though, we literally can't cast 100 downvotes and/or close votes a day.

Comment: Yes, I miscalculated that, sorry, @KevinB. It looks more like 100's a week, as far as I can determine the activity summary specifies.

Answer (score 11):

IMO close vote notification for low rep users would be good thing.

It is not that important for questions that get closed quickly but in many cases bad question will get close votes and/or down votes and new user will have no clue what is going on for large period of time.

Leaving comment to user that question is not good enough leads to all kind of responses. If you get *"Thanks, I didn't know that, I will improve/delete/ask on another site"* all is good, but more often you will get response *"My question is just fine"*, *"If you don't want/don't know how to answer go mind your own business"* and similar, sometimes accompanied with personal attack on commentator that was only trying to provide useful information to new user.

If *"bad question"* notification would come from Stack Overflow itself, such users might more easily realize they have to do something to improve and learn about asking questions rather than feel being personally attacked like it is the case right now.

Answer (score 5):

**Original Answer**

No, not until [250 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) (View Close Votes privilege).

The exception of course is duplicates, which post a comment with the potential dupe target.

**Edit Answer**

I echo Jon Clements [concerns](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300464/why-dont-we-give-users-below-250-rep-notion-about-close-votes/300465?noredirect=1#comment227107_300464), primarily that they *won't know what it means, or how to do anything about it*. Its hard enough to get a new user to find the little "edit" link below their post, now there will be another link they probably don't notice, and even if they did, wouldn't understand.

The education barrier seems too high for this to have the intended effect (which I *do* think we want, that is, helping new users understand what is happening/how things work).

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, why the OP shouldn't receive a notification.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Didn't see your edit :)

Comment: Not your fault, the question evolved a bit, and I' m lame from my tablet ;-) ..

Comment: Actually the "puzzled" thing is a bit worse than he says, because sometimes there's a fluke vote which does not make sense. Also, they are too likely to fixate on those votes, pleading and threatening, like for downvotes and actually finished closings...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Well, at least that link to a close reason is, what they will see, after the process is finished. So we just leave them puzzled after that point?  That' s better than informing the OP beforehand, Really? Isn't the information given with possible close reasons clear enough?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Perhaps I don't fully understand your proposal, but just removing the 250 rep requirement (at least for viewing) doesn't solve much because users won't see it (among the other issues that have been pointed out). Putting up a giant "Your question might be awful!" could work better, but I'm not sure *thats* a good idea either.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I'm proposing to sent them a notification actively for each of these kind of events (via email if they've been choosing so). I don't worry if that would appear _scary_ for them, may be just good so.

Answer (score 2):

I believe in notifying low rep users that their question is in danger of being put on hold, but I *don't* think the notification should be automatic.

The vast majority of bad questions come from users in Kendra's classes 1-3. I suspect that most of those people don't really care about how Stack Exchange works, and they probably haven't read much of the info on the Help pages. So they'd probably just ignore automatic notifications, or react badly to them.

I like to put a constructive comment on close-worthy questions (if I think the question is salvageable) and give the OP 10 minutes or so to respond before I vote to close. True, some users respond with hostility to such comments, but when that happens I just down-vote, vote to close, (possibly flagging a comment if it's excessively nasty), and move on.

I suppose that an automatic private notification coming from "the system" *may* be less likely to invoke a hostile response, but that's not guaranteed. An automatic notification might be able to tell the OP why their question is getting close votes and even to offer broad suggestions as to how to improve the question, but IMO such a notification would be less effective in getting the OP to repair their question than what can be achieved by a few strategic comments. When you're frustrated & confused it's nice to get a helping hand from an actual human, an automatic notification can simply add to the frustration & confusion.

I'm *not* advocating that we should waste time on users that won't appreciate our efforts. IME, it's usually pretty easy to tell if a new user is willing to learn about how Stack Exchange sites work, from the way they respond to comments. If the OP acts like one of Kendra's class 4 users, then there's a good chance that they want to do the right thing and will respond positively to helpful suggestions and relevant Help page links.

So I'd like to encourage others to post a constructive comment on questions that look like they could be salvageable. If the OP doesn't respond or responds badly, by all means vtc, but at least give them some time to understand what's wrong with their question.

I guess the OP has plenty of time to fix their question *after* it's been closed, but how many of us diligently visit old questions that we've closed to see if they've been improved? (It'd be nice if close voters were notified of edits on questions they've closed, but that's a topic for another Meta question.)

[Edit in response to Deduplicator's comments]

Also, I suspect many new users are discouraged when their question is put on hold & don't bother trying to fix it, although some post a re-worked version as a new question, rather than fixing the original question like they ought to.

Comment: Are you saying the reopen-queue *does not work*? Because if it does, we really don't have to check back for that...

Comment: @Deduplicator: The reopen-queue works, but how many of us think to check it regularly?

Comment: As it is nearly always empty, *enough of us*?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Ok. (Note to self: check the re-open queue more regularly, you lazy #$%! ) :)

Comment: I vote to close, then leave a comment about why I'm voting to close. This is mainly because users don't actually read the banner that is appended to the question. So I post a comment which basically repeats the important info from the banner, then I repeat all of the same information in much more specific terms. Sometimes I repeat myself again depending on how egregious the question is. This has seemed to provide better results.

Comment: For example, my "No MCVE" comment is as follows: Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please actually read the preceding link and make sure that the code you post **in your question** is **minimal** (only bare minimum of code necessary to reproduce), **complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **verifiable** (we can reproduce the issue using only the code in your question). Without a proper MCVE **in your question**, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.